# div with absolute position gets hidden

Tags: html, css

Here is my simple code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.three {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

And this is how the [output](https://jsfiddle.net/nerd1/se407wt3/6/) looks in `JSFiddle`. Now, classes, one and two have absolute positions, so they are no longer part of the normal document flow. So, class three which is red, shifts to the top. I understand that. But what happened to class one (yellow) and class two (blue)? I think class three should have shifted to the top and overlapped with both class one and class two. So, what is happening here ?

Comment: due to use of 'absolute' tag, the yellow and blue divs get overlapped by red, and hide behind red. You can test by removing 'position:absolute' in both class one & two

Comment: you need to give your divs a width

Comment: when you use the absolute position for div without content, you need to set the width and height, our use (content: " ";) in css.

Answer (score 2):

Main point is there are you mentioned height of `absolute` divs but never mentioned the width. So the `absolute` divs are not disappeared but they not showing because of zero width.

We should kept our mind that when you set any element as a `absolute` it should set `width`, `height`, put content inside it or mention `left` `right` coordinate.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w1agq7r8/).

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0 ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
  background: yellow ;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px ;
  position: absolute ;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  height: 400px ;
  position: absolute ;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
}

.three {
  background: red ;
  height: 300px ;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">

</div>

<div class="two">

</div>

<div class="three">

</div>
```

Comment: zero width makes sense. so with width set up, we do see yellow and blue boxes. But shouldn't red box (position: static) overlap yellow and blue boxes since yellow and blue are no longer part of the normal document flow ?

Answer (score 0):

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). If you want to display all three divs, you can try this:

```
.one {
  background: yellow ;
  height: 100px ;
}

.two {
  background: blue ;
  height: 400px ;
}
```

You just need to remove position:absolute as it works like a fixed position. I hope it helps. If still any queries, feel free to discuss!

Comment: class one has height of 100px and class two has height of 400px. Since, both have absolute positions, both will shift upward with net height of 400px. But class three has height of 300px. So, we should be able to see blue class two even if class three overlaps two classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see hidden div, so you need to add a z-index property.

```css
.one {
  background: yellow ;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px ;
  position: absolute ;
  /* Increase numbers as your need */
  z-index: 1;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  height: 400px ;
  position: absolute ;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  /* Increase numbers as your need */
  z-index: 2;
}

.three {
  background: red ;
  height: 300px ;
}
```